# Why is my controller breaking my code?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, ionic-framework

I am running a ionic project and I visualize it live with the Ionic Lab tool. It is pretty good because each time I modify a html doc, it shows live what's going on.

Now, I have inserted a controller at the bottom of my controllers.js and it just breaks my project. What I mean by that is that if I take the code off of the controllers.js file, the project shows up normally but if I put it, it justs make the entire project go blank. Like if nothing was on it.

Here is the code I added :

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
        //Authentication details.
            JSON.stringify(firebase.auth().currentUser));

            //Get logged in user credentials.
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var name, email, photoUrl, provider;

        if (user != null) {
        name = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;
        photoUrl = user.photoURL;
        provider = user.provider;
            }

            //Set Profile Image.
            profileImage = photoUrl;
            //Set Profile Name.
            profileName = name;
        //It is now up to you to set provider and email!    
  })
});
```

And here is my complete document :

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.signIn = function() {
        $state.go('tab.dash');
    };

    $scope.facebook = function() {
        var facebookAppId = "198040820571843";
        $cordovaOauth.facebook(facebookAppId, ["public_profile", "email"]).then(function(response) {
      var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.access_token);
      loginWithCredential(credential, 'Facebook');
    }, function(error) {
      //User cancelled login. Hide the loading modal.
    });
    }

    $scope.twitter = function() { 
    var twitterKey = "aJWByCgPhUgYZJMojyFeH2h8F";
        var twitterSecret = "XxqKHi6Bq3MHWESBLm0an5ndLxPYQ2uzLtIDy6f9vgKKc9kemI";
    $cordovaOauth.twitter(twitterKey, twitterSecret).then(function(response) {
      var credential = firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credential(response.oauth_token,
        response.oauth_token_secret);
      loginWithCredential(credential, 'Twitter');
    }, function(error) {
      //User cancelled login. Hide the loading modal.
    });
  };

    loginWithCredential = function(credential, provider) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then(function(response) {
        //User logged in through provider.
                $state.go('tab.dash');
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        //Show error message.
        var errorCode = error.code;
      });
  };
});

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
        //Authentication details.
            JSON.stringify(firebase.auth().currentUser));

            //Get logged in user credentials.
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var name, email, photoUrl, provider;

        if (user != null) {
        name = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;
        photoUrl = user.photoURL;
        provider = user.provider;
            }

            //Set Profile Image.
            profileImage = photoUrl;
            //Set Profile Name.
            profileName = name;
        //It is now up to you to set provider and email!    
  })
});
```

I really don't understand what is going on, it just breaks everything !

And I call that controller in the app.js :

```
.state('tab.account', {
      url: '/account',
      views: {
        'tab-account': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html'
        }
      },
      controller: 'AccountCtrl'
    })
```

If anybody has any help... Thanks !

EDIT , in the console, here is the error :

```
?ionicplatform=android:29 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js Line: 43console.(anonymous function) @ ?ionicplatform=android:29
controllers.js:43 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

It is the line that starts my controller of course...

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Well... I am a novice and I am still discovering. I don't really know how to show the console up but the one integrated in Ionic Lab doesn't show anything but the "serve" going fine...

I tried by CLI and that build the app without any problem, it is just... Blank ! And no errors showing up but once again I don't know if I really know how to show up the right console. 

Thank you for your time !

Comment: If it's in a browser you'd press F12 typically to see the console in the browser.

Comment: I edited my post with the error report at the end... I don't really know how to debug that !

Comment: What is on line 43 of `controllers.js`?

Comment: The code I try to add (first code shown in my original post) the "AccountCtrl"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120337/discussion-between-mariocatch-and-frenchynyc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

You have a trailing semicolon (`;`) on the controller `LoginCtrl`.

Your `AcctCtrl` cannot be fluently attached to your angular module because of that trailing semicolon on the controller above it.

Second,

This line has one too many closing `)`

`JSON.stringify(firebase.auth().currentUser));`

It should be:

`JSON.stringify(firebase.auth().currentUser);`

Answer (score 2):

From line:`41` remove the simi-colon, this breaks the chain of reference to angular.